# Getting Source code // File reader // returns empty list

Tags: java, url, arraylist, bufferedreader

I am trying to make a web-scraper that collects the top 100 music for everyday of the year. At the moment I am trying to write the function that collects the source code. I pretty much just copied and pasted it from my other scraper but for some odd reason it returns an empty list.

I believe we are working with the function get_source_code but I could be wrong. No error messages are returned. Help would be greatly appreciated thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MusicScraper {
    public static void main(String [] args)throws IOException {
        parse_source_code(get_source_code("","",""));

    }
    public static List<String> get_source_code(String day, String month, String year)throws IOException{
        List <String> sourceC = new ArrayList<>();

        URL link = new URL("https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/2017-02-25");             //"http://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day );

        HttpsURLConnection billboardConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) link.openConnection();
        billboardConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
        billboardConnection.connect();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(billboardConnection.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sourceC.add(inputLine);
        }
        System.out.println(sourceC);
        return sourceC;
    }

    public static List<String> parse_source_code(List<String> sourceCode){
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();

        List<String> rank = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> song = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> artist = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < sourceCode.size(); i++) {
            if (sourceCode.get(i).contains("data-songtitle=\"")) {
                String parsedSong = sourceCode.get(i).split("data-songtitle=\"")[1].split("\">")[0];
                song.add(parsedSong);
            }

}
        System.out.println(song);
        return sourceCode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you checked the response code of your request:

```
System.out.println(billboardConnection.getResponseCode());
```

You would see that it is returning a 301 error code (Moved Permanently).

Sometimes to scrape a URL returning a moved error, you would need to follow the redirect URL. However in this case, if you check the redirect URL (stored in the Location header field) you would see:

```
http://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/2017-02-25
```

This means that the your request is being downgraded from https to http, and so you can easily solve your issue by just using http in the first place:

```
URL link = new URL("http://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/2017-02-25");
```

Comment: This makes sense, thank you. Although it makes sense i now receive  a new error msg because it is not an https as specified in the code which code would I have to add or remove.

Comment: @Jblue you want to use `HttpURLConnection` instead of `HttpsURLConnection`.

Comment: @Jblue if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to yourself, and the user that provided the solution. There is no obligation to do this.